# Redux - can't pass props from parent?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a Container component that gets props via redux connect

### CONTAINER (SMART COMPONENT)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  someData: state.myReducer.someData
});
```

The same component renders its child and passes props to it:

```
<ChildComponent someData={this.props.someData} />
```

Everything works as expected, but my `someData` is a JS-nested JSON object, so when I render something like this in my child:

### CHILD (DUMB COMPONENT)

```
<p>{this.props.someData.someProperty}</p>
```

I'm getting an error:

> Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined

I know, I know, I should wait for someData to load, so:

### CONTAINER (standard solution, not working?)

```
render() {
    let dataReady = this.props.someData;

    return (
      <div>
        {dataReady ? <ChildComponent data={this.props.someData} /> : null}
      </div>
    );
}
```

dataReady is true once VERY FIRST property of it is ready, so in my child component I'm getting `firstProperty` but every single other one is EMPTY.

So I tried to wait for the very last property of someData like this:

### CONTAINER (another not working solution)

```
render() {
      let dataReady = this.props.someData.lastProperty;

      return (
        <div>
          {dataReady ? <ChildComponent data={this.props.someData} /> : null}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

But of course

> Cannot read property `lastProperty` of undefined

What am I doing wrong? How should I pass these props? I try to pass empty someData array to my container, but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: `<p>{this.props.someData.someProperty}</p>` refers to 'someData' but you pass it in as the prop `data={this.props.someData}`.  the prop is called 'data' in the child.

Comment: Nope, just a typo in example, I'm passing `someData`.

Comment: Can you try logging in mapStateToProps to see it's being called or not? 
It'll be a bit more helpful if your add the complete code for your component, all the steps you've done here seem to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a short circuit to use an empty object literal if `this.props.someData` is `undefined`. If `someData` is `undefined`, `{}.lastProperty` will be `undefined` as well.

```
let dataReady = (this.props.someData || {}).lastProperty;
```

Comment: This way I'm getting no errors but ChildComponent never renders.

Comment: console `this.props.someData` to see it's values, and see if it's defined and contains `lastProperty`, and if the value of `lastProperty` is not falsy.

Comment: Where should I console log it? I can't do that within child because it never renders and can't do it within parent container, because everywhere I try  I'm getting `cannot read property lastProperty of someData`.

Comment: `console.log(this.props.someData)` before the `let dataReady`.

Comment: I'm getting undefined like 4 times (there are many redux dispatches going on) but then I'm getting whole object that looks a-okay and is filled with non-falsy values. I do not understand a thing :/ The whole waiting thing makes me think its an antipattern, the app will not look okay if I will have to wait for one component much longer than for others.

Comment: You might want to render the child component, but only render the parts that are ready. Why is your nested object updated in stages?

Comment: It's not an antipattern to wait until data is ready to display, it's normal and one of the advantages of single page app design.  You can show *something* to the user ASAP and then gradually fill in the details as data becomes available.   Depending on the component, you can show a replacement value (a Loading... div, a spinner) for pieces that aren't ready to render yet.  If the entire view looks janky without all pieces ready, you can show a spinner until the entire view is ready to render.

Comment: Okay I got that, I think I made a mistake, my lastProperty is actually `someData.someOtherProperty.lastProperty`. I tried updating short circuit but of course it ends up with the same error as everywhere above. @brub what I meant it shouldn't break the app, I'd love to pass this.props.undefined.foo and still render the component, but empty and once undefined is defined it will work as expected. Now I'm either breaking the app or waiting for the whole child component to be ready.

Comment: `let dataReady = (this.props.someData.someOtherProperty || {}).lastProperty;` ends up with `Cannot read property 'someOtherProperty' of undefined`, is there an elegant solution for this @OriDrori? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Wordpressor - I think that you've got a problem in your state structure. Try to normalize it, and make it flatter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like rather than short-circuiting the child render, you want to render the child with an empty string?  In that case in the child render method display the empty string until the value is ready:

```
const displayVal = (this.props.someData && this.props.someData.someOtherProperty) ? this.props.someData.someOtherProperty.lastProperty : '';

<p>{displayVal}</p>
```

Comment: I think I might want to render the component with empty props and then wait for them to update. The problem is I have there like 90 properties and I'm not sure it will be possible to define all of them in the container. Also it feels like antipattern again. The problem I have here is waiting for the `last Property` makes no sense. What if back-end changes order and `lastProperty` becomes first property? :)

Comment: yeah there is something fishy going on with a big 'someData' object that updates in steps.  I didn't realize that lastProperty literally meant an index in an object.  You probably want to break up the pieces that update atomically into separate props.